# Why ssh-agent doesn't forward my SSH certificate?

Tags: ssh, certificate, ssh-agent

> This thread is a response to the titled question : **Why ssh-agent doesn't forward my SSH certificate ?**
>   Actually I couldn't find any information during my search. I had to [read the C code of ssh-add](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/22376d27a349f62c502fec3396dfe0fdcb2a40b7/ssh-add.c)
>   to resolve my issue..

### Problem

I got a valid SSH Certificate :

```
$ ssh-keygen -L -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub 
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub:
    Type: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate
    Public key: RSA-CERT SHA256:YgFzKPkUdZHLLi8bEKUs5/hLumNoMNG+oDJ+KD6mS3s
    Signing CA: RSA SHA256:w+Cjpu/QQUunuojs9Af82ENdBUreCDXo+APao9X4dHw
    Key ID: "user_key"
    Serial: 0
    Valid: from 2017-12-06T10:53:00 to 2017-12-07T10:54:57
    Principals: 
            user
            admin
    Critical Options: (none)
    Extensions: 
            permit-X11-forwarding
            permit-agent-forwarding
            permit-port-forwarding
            permit-pty
            permit-user-rc
```

This is my ssh-agent list of keys :

```
$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:YgFzKPkUdAGBPi8bEKUs5/hLumNoAds+oDJ+KD6mS3s user_key (RSA)
```

When I SSH on a remote server, it works. I have no `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and my key is probably well forwarded because I got the same previous result.

Now I would like to SSH to another server from the first one (with `ForwardAgent yes`):

```
$ ssh srv1
srv1:~$ ssh srv2 -vvv
...
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user_key
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
srv1:~$
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: You should post the answer part as a answer to this question (and remove it from the question itself)

Answer (score 9):

In fact, ssh-agent didn't took well my SSH Certificate. We can see that it is an `RSA` and not a `RSA-CERT`.
How import a certificate in ssh-agent ?

You must have 2 couple keys (location and naming is important) :

- Original RSA couple :

  - Private Key : ~/.ssh/example_key
  - Public Key : ~/.ssh/example_key **.pub**
- RSA Certificate :

  - Private Key/Certificate : ~/.ssh/example_key **-cert**
  - Public Certificate : ~/.ssh/example_key **-cert.pub**

Then import the original couple :

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/example_key
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/example_key: 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/example_key (/home/user/.ssh/example_key)
Certificate added: /home/user/.ssh/example_key-cert.pub (user)
```

Automatically, the certificate is added.

Then, the SSH agent forwards it without a problem. Meanwhile, it is impossible to delete from the agent the original RSA Key couple without removing the SSH certificate.

```
$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:YgFzKPkUdAGBPi8bEKUs5/hLumNoAds+oDJ+KD6mS3s user_key (RSA)
4096 SHA256:YgFzKPkUdAGBPi8bEKUs5/hLumNoAds+oDJ+KD6mS3s user_key (RSA-CERT)
$ ssh srv1
srv1:~$ ssh srv2
srv2:~$
```

---

### Recap : Why was wrong and why ?

- Bad naming of my keys. My RSA couple was something like `~/.ssh/id_rsa_github` and my SSH certificate was `~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert`.
- Agent import badly my certificate and consider it as a Identity and not a Certificate.
- During the first SSH connection, the agent provides the certificate as a Identity but it could negotiate with the remote openssh server (I don't really know why). During the second SSH connection, it couldn't...

Be also careful to this :

- Add `permit-agent-forwarding` in certificate extensions
- Put `ForwardAgent yes` in your SSH client configuration

Finally, to sign certificates I use CASSH.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. One suggestion I have is to clarify the naming convention for the cert. It works only if you add -cert.pub at the end of the cert file. You put it out there with space but not mentioned clearly.